# Attaching user to entities in MVC application with .NET Membership

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

In my Entity Framework, MVC application I am using .Net Membership (I wrote a custom provider). My questions are:

1. How do I best handle attaching the user to entities I create?
2. Is it acceptable to attach navigation properties to my User Entity that extends IPrincipal or should I be keeping it "clean"?

Currently in every action in which I attach a new entity to a user, I first have to look-up the user. Then frequently, because I do not have navigation properties on my User, I need to do a second query to get results from a different DbSet?

So simplifying, a controller could look like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
        User u = UserRepository.FindById((int)Membership.getUser().ProviderUserKey);
        List<OtherObject> oList = OtherRepository.FindByUser(u);
}
```

What I would like to do is something like:

```
public ActionResult Index() {
        List<OtherObject> oList = provider.User.OtherObjectList;
        // or
        List<OtherObject> oList = Membership.GetUser().OtherObjectList;
}
```

But I am not sure this would be correct with respect to how I should use membership (with the user only holding login/account required information.

And a final question on this, this is how my membership user is currently being returned:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline) {
        User u = UserRepository.FindByUsername(username);
        MembershipUser memU = null;
        if (u != null) {
            // 
            memU = new MembershipUser("MyMembershipProvider",
                        username, u.UserID, u.Email, string.Empty,
                        u.Comment, u.IsApproved, u.IsLockedOut, u.CreationDate,
                        u.LastLoginDate, u.LastActivityDate, u.LastPasswordChangeDate,
                        u.LastLockedOutDate);
        }
        return memU;
    }
```

So I look up the user and create a new `MembershipUser`, which I then use to immediately look up the user again in the controller - seems a bit redundant, but is this just what I should do?

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework Code-first or Model/Database-first with EDMX diagram?

Comment: Code first, and not auto generating my DB.